# Robolectric & Android (WARNING: no system properties value for ro.control_privapp_permissions)

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, robolectric

I'm running robolectric ver3.4.2 tests in Android Studio 3.0 beta & 2.3. Tests are behaving normally but I get these warnings:

```
WARNING: no system properties value for ro.control_privapp_permissions
WARNING: no system properties value for ro.crypto.state
WARNING: no system properties value for ro.crypto.type
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I assume it is a similar issue with [reported](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1251) several years ago. Looking to [the Robolectric sources](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/shadows/framework/src/main/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowSystemProperties.java) I don't see emulating these properties. And most probably AOSP code [needs](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based) them and warns about absence.